# Перечисления и мой пример

Tags: java

Не могу понять отличия от обычных констант и перечислений.
Понятно, что если в классе нужна одна константа легче сделать:

```
public static final String name = "Tom";
```

А когда много констант сделать это перечислениями

```
 public class Example {
        public static final String PINK = "PINK";
        enum Color { GREEN, BLUE, RED};
        enum Size {BIG, SMALL, MEDIUM };

        void color(Color c) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        void size(Size c) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }

        void main() {
            Example e = new Example();
            e.color(PINK); // Тут компилятор ругается
            e.color(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
```

Но я вот сделал вот такой пример и увидел, что допустим здесь играет уже типизация, не принимает константу ибо она `String`, а не с типом `Color`, правильно ли я сделал пример и понял?

Comment: Это верно, но не это главное в перечислениях. См. ответ на свой предыдущий вопрос.

Comment: Не очень понятно, в чем вопрос? Правильно ли понял - очевидно нет, если код не компилируется. Почему не компилируется - из-за строгой типизации. Ваш конструктор принимает переменную типа Color, а вы ему пытаетесь втолкнуть String (от того, что этот String еще и final еготип не меняется, он по прежнему String). Посему , если действительно есть непонимание, перефразируйте как-то...

Comment: @Дмитрий я сделал пример, чтобы посмотреть в чем отличие старых констант от перечислений (новых констант), правильно ли я понял данный пример показывает их разницу?

Comment: Давайте еще раз... Здесь не читают мысли. Ваш код доказывает, что в джаве работает строгая типизация. Перечисление - это тип данных. Константа - это не тип данных. Константой можно объявит любую перемнную.